# Can anyone help me on how to install/use django-extrawidgets 1

Tags: python, django, widget

I am very new to django and I have a problem on how to install or use the `django-extrawidgets 1`. After I have downloaded it, where to put it is where I am a bit confused with.

- django-rays' `setup.py` has an automatic dependency on django-staticfiles,
  so installing django-rays automatically brings in django-staticfiles.
- Add both `rays` and `staticfiles` to your settings file's
  `INSTALLED_APPS`."

I have write it in .."INSTALLED_APPS" but then it gives an error "No module name rays".

The reason I need this is because I need to use the extra widget for `datepicker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should read line

> Add both `rays` and `staticfiles` to your settings file's `INSTALLED_APPS`.

as

> Add both **`django_extrawidgets`** and `staticfiles` to your settings file's `INSTALLED_APPS`.

It was renamed the package and in the manual there is an old name.

```
$ cd django-extrawidgets-1/
$ sudo python setup.py install
... bla bla bla ...
$ python
>>> import django_extrawidgets # work fine
>>> help(django_extrawidgets)
...
PACKAGE CONTENTS  # it's seems to django app, what you need.
    models
    templatetags (package)
    validation
    views
    widgets
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying..:) i manage to installed it and look like what you have told...but when i try to runserver "python manage.py runserver" i get an error: no module named django_extrawidgets...

Comment: Hi defuz. i figure it out and manage to runserver..i did write "django.contrib.django_extrawidgets" instead the correct one is "django_extrawidgets".